# How to delete a word from the csv file

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

How to delete a word from the csv file when it is used so as not to have the same question twice with the same word and stop when all the words have been used?

```
import extensions.CSVFile;
```

```
CSVFile wordPrice = loadCSV("wordPrice");
```

```
class Word {
 String word;
 int price;
}
```

```
void play (Word info) {
 
  int RightPrice = info.price;
  int Price;
  println("What is the price of a" + info.word);
 
 
  do{
   counter = counter + 1;
   Price = readInt(); 
   if (Price<RightPrice){
    println("It's +");
   }
         else if (Price>RightPrice) {
    println("It's -");
   }
  }
```

```
Word randWord(){
  Word mp = new Word();
     int line = (int)(random() * rowCount(wordPrice)); 
     mp.word = getCell(wordPrice, line, 0);
     String price = getCell(wordPrice, line, 1);
      mp.price = stringToInt(price);
     return mp;
    }
```

```
boolean replay(boolean exit) {
 
        println("Do you wan to play again (Y : Yes, N : No) ?");
        char answer = readChar();
 
 
        if(answer == 'N') {
            exit = true;
        }
        if(answer == 'Y') {
            exit = false;
        }
        return exit;
    }
```

```
void algorithm(){;
        println("Find the price of items to win !");

        boolean exxite = false;
        while(exxite == false) {
            Word randWord = randWord();
            play(randWord);
            exxite = replay(exxite);
        }
    }
```

csv name: wordPrice.
There are two columns, one with the words and the other with the prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for that HashMap with key as a word and value as a price. Then just use this data structure in your algorithm.

So it could be something like that:

```
// CSV to map
Map<String, String> wordAndPrice = new HashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wordPrice.csv"))) {
  String currentLine;
  while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = currentLine.split(",");
    wordAndPrice.put(values[0], values[1]);
  }
};

// remove unused words from map (use Iterator because you can get ConcurrentModification exception)
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = wordAndPrice.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  if (iterator.next().getKey().equals("Your word"))
    iterator.remove();
}
```

As you pointed tag ***OpenCSV***, you can use it to load csv file instead of ***BufferedReader***:

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("wordPrice.csv"));
```